# android gps stack overflow in database

Tags: android, gps

So I am able to get the longitude and latitude of my location using gps. Problem is, I think I'm doing something wrong in saving it in the database. When I try to call the database an error shows up saying "Stack Overflow". I'm thinking it might be because the gps code is in a thread. You see, I try to call the gps function until it can get my current location but it doesn't stop there.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    if (loc != null) {
        longitude = "" + getLongitude();
        latitude = "" + getLatitude();
        Toast.makeText(this, longitude + "latitude: " + latitude, 2).show();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? * edited*

Comment: If `loc == null`, what does it mean to call methods on your `null` reference? If it _isn't_ `null`, perhaps it would make sense, but I would go further to store the results of the first two method calls to use them in the `Text`, rather than calling the methods twice each.

Comment: What can I do to make the code stop when it has already found the location? :(

Comment: How you stop your code depends in part on how you started it -- perhaps you need to remove your `onLocationChanged()` callback function from a GPS manager once it has been called? Perhaps you need to set a flag with the GPS manager asking it to stop sending updates? Perhaps you need to update your location whenever the location has moved more than a given amount? Some of it is up to you and your application, some of it might be forced by the design of the API you're using.

Comment: hi guys! thanks for the help! I finally made it work. I didn't use onLocationChanged() anymore instead I used getLastKnownLocation() and it seems that I made some mistake on my database :D

Comment: Don't forget to add your solution as an answer and accept it, so others can more easily find out what worked. :)

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot the time limitation for new users. Oh well, once it expires, don't forget about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

So the reason why I was always getting a stack overflow error was because I was saving the wrong data into the database. At first, I entered my line as showLatitude.add(cursor.getString(11)) when it should be showLatitude.add(cursor.getString(14)). Hope this helps?

```
public void putlocation(String longitude, String latitude){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("longitude", longitude);
    cv.put("latitude",latitude);
    db.insert("todo", null, cv);
    db.close(); 
}

public ArrayList<String> showLatitude(){    
    ArrayList<String> showLatitude = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("todo",null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                showLatitude.add(cursor.getString(14));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return showLatitude();  
}
```

Comment: The last line of this code is a recursive call that will cause a stack overflow exception. I believe you want it to read:
    return showLatitude;
Generally, having variables with the same name as your method can be confusing and cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see an error in the code you posted, however it should generate a NullPointerException, not a StackOverflowException.

The contents of your if statement are only executed if loc == null, but if this is true then loc.getlatitude() should throw a NullPointerException as you can not call a method on a null variable.

I think your code should be

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    if(loc != null) { 
        Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude = " + loc.getLongitude(); 
    } 
}
```

StackOverflow Exceptions occur when too many method calls are put on the call stack, this is usually symptomatic of a recursive method gone wrong.

Comment: So my new code is like this 'public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
 if(loc != null) {

 latitude = "" + loc.getLatitude();
 longitude = "" + loc.getLongitude();
   
 Toast.makeText(Messenger.this, longitude + " latitude = " + latitude, 2).show();
}'